# Charging an 8 V, 100 mA device via USB (5 V, 500 mA)

Tags: usb, 5v

I have a shaver (Philips QP2530) which I would like to be able to charge via a USB outlet (in order to allow me to use it on a motorcycle ride from London to Tokyo, but that's another story!)

The shaver's standard power adapter output is 8 V and 100 mA DC

What would happen if I connect the shaver to a regular USB outlet (5 V, 500 mA)?

I calculate the shaver charger to be 0.8 W and the USB to be 2.5 W - but will the shaver only pull the wattage it needs as the voltage is higher?

Keen to hear your thoughts! I'm trying to teach myself about electronics, so bear with me if it's a stupid question.

Comment: the problem may be the voltage ... it may not be high enough to run the charger ... the current is no problem ... the charger will draw only what it needs ... give it a try and see if the shaver charges from 5 V

Answer (score 4):

What will happen if you connect 5V directly to the shaver? Probably nothing bad. Most likely nothing at all: it won't charge. If I had to speculate (and I do) there's two 3.8V lithium cells in series in this shaver, so to charge these using a cheap linear regulator you need at least 7.6V, so 8V input can run that with a wee bit of margin.

It's possible to convert USB 5V to shaver 8V using a DC-DC step-up converter. 100mA is a modest current so it should be easy to build... or buy (see below.)

Here's one on eBay, but you may find others that are more suitable: https://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-DC-DC-5V-to-6V-7V-8V-9V-12V-15V-Adj-Step-up-Boost-Converter-UPS-Power-Supply-/172143724776

Here's another: https://www.diymore.cc/products/dc-dc-usb-5v-to-6-15v-step-up-boost-converter-voltage-inverters-module-adjustable-board-output-dc-6v-7v-8v-9v-12v

And here's a cord that claims to be **the very thing you're seeking**: [https://www.amazon.com/Charger-Philips-Norelco-Replacement-Oneblade/dp/B081XX24M9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081XX24M9)

Happy shopping... or making.

---

Here is an example of an IC that would allow you to make your own boost converter with a very few additional components - [TPS61046 datasheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61046.pdf). The main disadvantage of this IC is the very small package it is supplied in.

[image]

---

If modest efficiency was acceptable then the ancient but very flexible and easy to use MC34063 - [datasheet here](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/03/f9/c4/3d/7f/eb/4c/5e/CD00001232.pdf/files/CD00001232.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001232.pdf) $US0.59 in 1's from Digikey in 8 pin DIP package. Note the much larger inductor due to the much lower operating frequency and other example design factors. See datasheet for (easy) design guidelines. A sample PCB layout is provided.

From fig 13 in the data sheet.
R1 R2 again set Vout.
C3 sets clock frequency. 
The 0.22 Ohm resistor is an optional current limit sensor.

[image]

Comment: You can make pretty URLs when you use the link button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: And... sometimes I do. Other times, like this one, I prefer to let the user *see* the URL, especially when it links to eBay or other e-commerce site, so they can decide for themselves if they want to click through. Yes, if it’s a link they can mouse-over it to see the URL, but it’s not quite as up-front.

Comment: Also shopping and usage questions are off-topic.

Comment: I could not disagree more in this case. Make-vs-buy is *always* a consideration in engineering. It is very much on-topic to go over theory, identify requirements, *show examples*, and let the user decide how they want to proceed armed with new knowledge.

Comment: I see the Rules Lawyers have made their presence felt. Folks like you do a real disservice to SE.

Comment: Downvoting this question demonstrates a lack of understanding of what down voting is about. The criteria is "This answer is useful / not useful". This answer IS useful. QED.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon This answer encourages people to post bad off-topic questions, and makes SE a worse place.

Comment: @pipe You may be right - although it's moot. BUT that was not what I commented on. Downvotes are not to indicate that answers are mauve, pretty, smelly, antediluvian or shy. The stated criteria is useful or not. It's useful. People are welcome (enough :-) ). to express their opinions in comments, and/or to vote to close. || ...

Comment: ... The overriding requirement of Q&As for this site (stated by one of the founders) is to produce long lasting Q&As which will attract search engine traffic [to help the owners make money] . In this case there is a good concise explanation of the 5V - 8V unsuitability  reason, indication re non-harm,  suggestion re design, and indication that 5V to 8V cords exist (who knew). Overall this Q&A is as able to inform people in a range of related areas on an ongoing basis.    | The large majority of questions have a shoppungish content....

Comment: The site is not [my end of your perspective] harmed by such Q&A if the answers are good (as this is) and while they add to the volume they do so usefully enough and better than numerous "proper" Q&As.  || The cord is just a small inline boost converter but knowing they exist has added to my knowledge base.

Comment: My goal as an answerer is to provide a useful - and possibly entertaining - answer that respects the asker. I do this because it’s fun. When the weasels come along and rip my flesh about this or that, it harshes my mellow. It’s why I took a break from SE some months ago, after having the same old run-ins with certain individuals over what constituted an ‘on-topic’ question or answer. Frankly speaking, using that narrow (and wrong) interpretation of the rules often makes for a dull, boring and ultimately less useful SE. Answerers like me are the lifeblood of SE. Ima keep up the good fight.

Comment: @hacktastical You sound like an old curmudgeon - like [me](http://bit.ly/oldgreyguy) - whether so or not, keep up the good work :-)

Comment: Did the Zappa reference give me away? (We are talking about shavers, see...)

Comment: @hacktastical See my edits. Remove if you like. Aim is to add to existing DIY content. || Note that LiIon cells are nominally rated at 3.6 or 3.7V mean but full voltag is 4.2V, and 4V represents a voltage at which they can be safely floated. MUST NOT be floated at 4.2V!. So the 8V will charge and float 2 x LiIon cells. | Philips have long been keen on NimH but probably not using them here. NimH needs 1.4 -  1.5V for full charge so eg 8v/5-cells = 1.6V/cell = too high. 8V/6-cells = 1.33v/cell = much too low. So could use 5S NimH with regulator BUT probably 2S LiIon.

Comment: @hacktastical Nah - you just have the air of a want to be helpful, damn the torpedoes, too much like me :-), can't understand the drive to notional purity rather than seeking to both meet the stated prime directive (make the owners money) AND help people as well.

Comment: Hi all, apolgies for the late response, I was struck down with a fever over the weekend. Thanks for explaining what can & can't be done in such clear detail, really helpful. On this occasion I might spend the additional few £ and get the pre-made cable, but it helps my understanding for the main project which will be to re-wire the bike I'm going on! Many thanks, Matt

Answer (score -1):

Considering someone makes [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32960656960.html) it might work to connect it directly, but you'll probably have terrible charging effeciency.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: I don’t see his shaver on the list. Are you sure it’s compatible?

Comment: To my knowledge Philips uses the same connector for most of their grooming products, the cable that I mentioned is most likely just a pass through cable. Assuming Philips used a similar charging circuit to their other products, it may work. If you want to be sure you'll have to take it apart and measure the battery current when applying 5V.

Comment: There's variants of this shaver: a less expensive one that takes a 4.3V input (QP2520), and this one (QP2530) that takes 8V. Regardless of the connector, the voltage has to be correct.

Comment: Many thanks guys - you're correct mine is the QP2530 which requires an 8 V input. Kind regards, Matt